# How to read a text file with regional language from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I m trying to read the text file with regional language and and display in the message box. But text is converted into some other standard and displayed. How to display text in message box as it is in text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the regional characters are covered in the Unicode, you might want to try the following :

`Dim textFromFile as string = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\regionalfile.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)`

(Or UFT32, UFT8, UFT7, BigEndianUnicode or default. Default is ANSI.)